# Leetcode problem "valid sudoku": what is wrong with my solution?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [36. Valid Sudoku](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/description/):

> Determine if a 9 x 9 Sudoku board is valid. Only the filled cells need to be validated **according to the following rules**:
>
> 1. Each row must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
> 2. Each column must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
> 3. Each of the nine 3 x 3 sub-boxes of the grid must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
>
> #### Note:
>
> - A Sudoku board (partially filled) could be valid but is not necessarily solvable.
> - Only the filled cells need to be validated according to the mentioned rules.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:** `board =`
>
> ```
> [["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."]
> ,["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."]
> ,[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."]
> ,["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"]
> ,["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"]
> ,["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"]
> ,[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."]
> ,[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"]
> ,[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]
> ```
>
> **Output:** true
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> **Input:** `board =`
>
> ```
> [["8","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."]
> ,["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."]
> ,[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."]
> ,["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"]
> ,["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"]
> ,["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"]
> ,[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."]
> ,[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"]
> ,[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]
> ```
>
> **Output:** false
>
> **Explanation:** Same as Example 1, except with the **5** in the top left corner being modified to **8**. Since there are two 8's in the top left 3x3 sub-box, it is invalid.

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board)
    {
        boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[10];// 1- 9 index1 means the number 1 index 0 will remain false
        int m = board.length;
        for(int a = 0 ; a < m ; a++)//repeats for all sub-boards
        {
            int currRow = (a/3)*3;
            for(int i = currRow ; i < currRow + 3 ; i++)//iterate over row 0 , 1 , 2 of the current sub-board
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
                {
                    
                    char e = board[i][j];//get the element in a row wise manner of the current row of the current sub-board 
                   
                    if( e == '.')                      continue;

                    if(isUnique[ e - '0'] == false)    isUnique[ e - '0'] = true;

                    else                               return false;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

I am not getting any syntax errors, but the code doesn't seem to pass the check after the 1st subboard, even when I believe the logic is correct to my understanding.

For the first example input (see above) my code failed to give the correct answer, while for the second input it passed.

Comment: Where in your code are you checking that on a horizontal line you don't have duplicate numbers? Where in your code are you checking that on a vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

Though Java--a language I don't know--is called for, I will give an answer in Ruby, with commentary, as I wish to illustrate how matrix methods could be used to advantage. I expect something similar could be done in Java and other languages. @trincot has described the problems with your code so I will say nothing about that (assuming I could).

Suppose we are given

```
arr = [
  ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
  ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
  [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
  ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
  ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
  ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
  [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
  [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
  [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
]
```

We may convert this to a matrix:

```
require 'matrix'
```

```
m = Matrix[*arr]
```

[image]

We can do the usual things with this matrix, such as extracting rows and columns, transposing and pulling out rectangular submatricies. To accomplish the last suppose we wished to extract the 3x3 matrix consisting of the intersection of rows with indices 6, 7, and 8 (i.e., within the range `6..8`) and columns within the range `3..5` (i.e., the bottom-middle 3x3 submatrix):

```
m.minor(6..8, 3..5)
```

[image]

---

We being by creating two constants.

```
TEMPLATE = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
MINORS = [0..2, 3..5, 6..8].product([0..2, 3..5, 6..8])
  #=> [[0..2, 0..2], [0..2, 3..5], [0..2, 6..8],
  #    [3..5, 0..2], [3..5, 3..5], [3..5, 6..8],
  #    [6..8, 0..2], [6..8, 3..5], [6..8, 6..8]]
```

---

Next we create a helper method.

```
def check(m)
  arr = m.to_a.flatten
  a = arr - ['.']
  return false unless a.all? { |s| TEMPLATE.include?(s) }
  a.size + (TEMPLATE - a).size == 9
end
```

`arr = m.to_a.flatten` converts the matrix or vector `m` to an array which is then flattened. If, for example, `m` were the minor array produced by `m.minor(6..8, 3..5)` (see earlier example), `arr` would be set equal to `["4", "1", "9", "8"]`. `a.size + (TEMPLATE - a).size` will equal `9` if and only if `a` contains no duplicates.

This returns true or false depending on whether the matrix or vector `m` contains only digits other than `"0"`and periods and there is no replication of digits.

---

One more helper method that checks that all rows are correct.

```
def check_rows(m)
  (0..8).all? { |r| check(m.row(r)) }
end
```

---

We may now write the main method and test it against the array `arr` defined earlier. (`&&` is logical 'and'.)

```
def valid?(arr)
  m = Matrix[*arr]
  check_rows(m)                                 && # check rows
  check_rows(m.transpose)                       && # check columns
  MINORS.all? { |minor| check(m.minor(minor)) }    # check 9 3x3 submatrices
end
```

```
valid?(arr)
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that it only checks the first 3x3 sub-board for duplicates and does not reset the `isUnique` array before moving to the next sub-board, column, or row. Moreover, it only iterates through the first column of sub-boards (leftmost column), missing the validation for the rest of the board.

A valid Sudoku checker must validate all rows, all columns, and all 9 of the 3x3 sub-boards separately. You need to reset your `isUnique` array for each validation step and ensure you're checking every row, column, and 3x3 sub-board. Here's a strategy to do so:

1. Iterate through each row to ensure no duplicate numbers exist.
2. Iterate through each column for the same purpose.
3. Iterate through each 3x3 sub-board.

To correct and optimize your solution, you can follow this approach:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {
        // Check rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (!isUnique(board, i, i + 1, 0, 9)) return false;
        }
        // Check columns
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (!isUnique(board, 0, 9, j, j + 1)) return false;
        }
        // Check 3x3 sub-boards
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3) {
                if (!isUnique(board, i, i + 3, j, j + 3)) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isUnique(char[][] board, int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd) {
        boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
        for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i++) {
            for (int j = colStart; j < colEnd; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == '.') continue;
                int num = board[i][j] - '0';
                if (seen[num]) return false;
                seen[num] = true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This approach separates the logic for checking uniqueness into a helper method `isUnique`, which is called for each row, column, and sub-board, ensuring the entire board is validated.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues in your attempt:

- You've only attempted to detect duplicates in 3x3 boxes, but you also need to detect duplicates that might exist on a single row, or on a single column.
- The code you have on 3x3 boxes only uses an index of 0, 1 or 2 for the column part (`j`), so you are checking the same 3x3 box multiple times and don't check the 3x3 boxes that exist in the center, nor at the far right. To fix this you need the concept of `currCol`, just like you did for `currRow`, but with the formula `currCol = (a%3)*3`.
- The duplicate detection will go wrong after a while because you never clear the contents of `isUnique`. Yet for each 3x3 box you need a fresh start, so that array should start with all `false` each time you start with a new box.

Here is your code with the corrections for the points above:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board)
    {
        boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[10];
        int m = board.length;
        for(int a = 0 ; a < m ; a++)
        {
            // Need to clear isUnique from previous results:
            Arrays.fill(isUnique, false);
            int currRow = (a/3)*3;
            for(int i = currRow ; i < currRow + 3 ; i++)
            {
                int currCol = (a%3)*3; // Need to get the horizontal offset too
                for(int j = currCol ; j < currCol + 3 ; j++) // and use it here
                {
                    char e = board[i][j];   
                    if( e == '.')                      continue;
                    if(isUnique[ e - '0'] == false)    isUnique[ e - '0'] = true;
                    else                               return false;
                }
            }
            // Also check vertical lines
            Arrays.fill(isUnique, false);
            for (int b = 0 ; b < m ; b++)
            {
                    char e = board[a][b];   
                    if( e == '.')                      continue;
                    if(isUnique[ e - '0'] == false)    isUnique[ e - '0'] = true;
                    else                               return false;
            }
            // Also check horizontal lines
            Arrays.fill(isUnique, false);
            for (int b = 0 ; b < m ; b++)
            {
                    char e = board[b][a];   
                    if( e == '.')                      continue;
                    if(isUnique[ e - '0'] == false)    isUnique[ e - '0'] = true;
                    else                               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

To avoid code repetition you could write a function that can be reused for the three types of 9-cell checks, by passing a `width` argument that indicates after how many columns the next row should be visited:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean checkArea(char[][] board, int row, int col, int width) 
    {
        boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[10];
        int addCol = 0;
        for (int cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++)
        {
            char e = board[row][col + addCol%width];
            addCol++;
            row += addCol%width == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            if (e == '.') continue;
            if (isUnique[e - '0']) return false;
            isUnique[e - '0'] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < board.length; a++)
        {
            if (!checkArea(board, a, 0, 9) ||
                !checkArea(board, 0, a, 1) ||
                !checkArea(board, (a/3)*3, (a%3)*3, 3)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```